# Amplifier does not sound right when balance is centered

Tags: amplifier, earth

I have an HK 590i amplifier.   When the balance is centered sound is like coming from far away (voices).  Sound is good only when balance is full left or right.
I researched the site and found this answer that seems related to my problem [Stereo heaphone doesn't work properly when the balance is centered](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140963/stereo-heaphone-doesnt-work-properly-when-the-balance-is-centered) .   I have the amplifier schematic.   I would like recommendation about where to look for the problem (broken earth connection I think).

Comment: Are you listening on speakers or headphones?

Comment: Phase on speaker is reversed ?

Comment: Related: [What is it that strips vocals from audio when a 1/8" audio jack is partially unplugged?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/42623/11683)

Answer (score 11):

Reverse the polarity of one of the speakers. It sounds as though you have one of them reversed and so they are out of phase. Vocals and bass are usually centered in the stereo panorama and when they are played out of phase on left and right channels they tend to cancel out in the centre of the stereo image.

The reason for this is that one speaker is pushing the air while the other is pulling. The net result is a cancellation or sum to zero at your ears.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you reference a reasonably similar problem: it very much sounds like the ground connection from your amplifier to the headphones is missing.  Whether that is a problem with your headphones or with the headphone socket or with any adapter you may be using in between is anybody's guess since you don't give any details about your setup.

An obvious test would be to try other headphones, and not use the same adapter in case one is involved here.