# Lm386 audio amplier - lyrics not audible

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, speakers, lm386

I am trying to amplify the music signal coming from a phone using an LM386 module for a 8ohm 3W speaker using a 5V supply,but when I connect it to the source,it amplifies a portion of the music,not all of it.The instrumental/background music can be heard,but not the lyrics(they are not audible). 
Please help. [image]

Comment: You've goofed on that part over there. Adjusting it to this value should fix it.

Comment: Looks similar to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42623/what-is-it-that-strips-vocals-from-audio-when-a-1-8-audio-jack-is-partially-unp

Comment: Please clarify your question.What do you mean by "when beats come" and "lyrics come"?

Comment: See basically when i connects it to the music signal it plays the beats but the vocal part is not audible

Comment: schematic or it didn't happen

Comment: Added module picture. Sorry i didn't find schematic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the input wired up wrong. What you should be doing is using two amplifiers; one for left and one for right but instead, you are taking the left and right signal (ignoring the common ground conenction) and feeding that to your amplifier. Because vocal and most bass stuff appears equally in left and right channels on most popular music, in effect, there is no net signal produced when you connect left to the input and right to the amplifier ground connection.

You get a similar effect on stereo speakers when one is wired in reverse - at certain points along the axis between the two speakers, bass sounds can dissapear. Many audio tools provide this feature too.

If you want to fix this try using two 1 kohm resistors to join left and right channels into one input and use the regular ground connection from your music source to connect to ground of your amplifier.

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4IbGgqTCFw) youtube video that explains what is happening when you invert one channel and add it to the other (which is basically what you are doing inadvertently).

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. I used Poweramp mono which which converted stereo track to mono track.

Comment: Can you please help, now i have another issue. Here is the link to the question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272726/bluetooth-and-amplifier-from-same-voltage-source